# Using Sweave and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, sweave, texshop

I'm doing a report that is heavy in `R` but also would like to use system fonts, so I was hoping to be able to use `Sweave` and `XeLaTeX`.

My preferred tex editor is TexShop (Mac 10.7), but it seems to only allow me to select *either* Sweave or XeLaTeX. I can produce a .tex file from Sweave and then manually run that through the XeLaTeX engine after adjusting the packages/fonts, but it seems like there must be an easier way.

It looked to me like RStudio had this functionality, but when I chose XeLaTeX as the typesetter it yields the error: `[object Uint8Array]' is not a valid argument for 'Function.prototype.apply'`, which looks like some sort of `C`-based code. The Sweave document that produces that error is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
Text
\end{document}
```

pdfLatex compiles it fine. Resources I checked on using XeLaTeX and Sweave don't address this issue as far as I've been able to see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make yourself a Sweave-XeLaTeX engine file for TeXShop.  To do this, do the following.

- Using the Go menu in the Finder, navigate to the TeXShop Engines folder by choosing Go and then entering `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`
- Make a Copy of the Sweave engine and rename it Sweave-XeLaTeX
- Open the engine in TeXShop and change the line

  ```
   pdflatex "${1%.*}"
  ```

  to

  ```
   xelatex "${1%.*}"
  ```

Save the file, and restart TeXShop.  You should now have a Sweave-XeLaTeX engine file in the dropdown menu next to the Typeset button.

You can also access the engine automatically in your .Rnw file by adding

```
% !TEX TS-program = Sweave-xelatex
```

as the first line of your file (you can choose this from the Macros -> Program menu item too.)

Comment: Thanks, works great! That's helpful in understanding how the different engines work too.